# How can I force my quest to progress?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I am working through the Flashpoint episode and am currently stuck on the quest, [Arrival and Survival](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Arrival_and_Survival).

My quest marker tells me to

> Check in with Vigil First Mate Bilgefire.

However, when I talk to him, I get the dialog, but then the quest does not update. What can I do try and force the game to update?

Things I have tried so far which do not work

- Rebooting the game
- Zoning out of the area and back in again
- Quitting the episode and restarting it

Comment: Have you seen the bug note towards the bottom of the page you link to? Oh, and it's a story, not a quest ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that this is a known issue as detailed on the wiki page.

> Its not possible right now to advance the story beyond the dialog
>   between Scientist Viraddi and First Mate Bilgefire. Logging out near
>   the end of the conversation and logging back in sometimes progresses
>   the story to the next step.